# Request for help repairing output of apt update

Tags: apt, repository, gpg, gnome-keyring, signature

This is the output of `sudo apt update`
I would appreciate it if someone could help me fix the problems, I'm only new to Linux.

I'm running (Linux kali 5.16.0-kali5-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT Debian 5.16.14-1kali1 (2022-03-15) x86_64 GNU/Linux).I have been trying to fix it for hours but I'm just damaging it more.

```
`Get:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-debian11-11-5-local  InRelease
 Ign:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-debian11-11-5-local  InRelease
 Get:2 file:/var/cuda-repo-debian11-11-5-local  Release [564 B]
 Get:2 file:/var/cuda-repo-debian11-11-5-local  Release [564 B]
 Hit:3 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian buster InRelease
 Hit:4 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian buster InRelease                         
 Err:5 file:/var/cuda-repo-debian11-11-5-local  Release.gpg                      
   The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not 
 available: NO_PUBKEY F60F4B3D7FA2AF80
 Hit:6 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                    
 Hit:7 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease                 
 Err:4 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian buster InRelease                         
   The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not 
 available: NO_PUBKEY 467B942D3A79BD29
 Hit:8 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/edge stable InRelease                
 Hit:9 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling InRelease                          
 Get:10 https://assets.checkra.in/debian  InRelease [2,170 B]             
 Hit:11 https://repo.protonvpn.com/debian stable InRelease   
 Err:10 https://assets.checkra.in/debian  InRelease
   The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not 
 available: NO_PUBKEY 7F9943C7A5217279
 Fetched 2,170 B in 2s (1,289 B/s)
 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree... Done
 Reading state information... Done
 4 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
 W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not 
 updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: file:/var/cuda-repo 
 debian11-11-5-local  Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because 
 the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F60F4B3D7FA2AF80
 W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not 
 updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: 
 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian buster InRelease: The following signatures couldn't 
 be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 467B942D3A79BD29
 W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not 
 updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: 
 https://assets.checkra.in/debian  InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be 
 verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 7F9943C7A5217279
 W: Failed to fetch https://assets.checkra.in/debian/InRelease  The following 
 signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 
 7F9943C7A5217279
 W: Failed to fetch http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/dists/buster/InRelease  The 
 following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: 
 NO_PUBKEY 467B942D3A79BD29
 W: Failed to fetch file:/var/cuda-repo-debian11-11-5-local/Release.gpg  The 
 following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: 
 NO_PUBKEY F60F4B3D7FA2AF80
 W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used 
 instead.`
```

Please how can it be fixed, the last thing I tried from [askubuntu][1][1]: https://askubuntu.com/questions/831386/gpgkeys-key-f60f4b3d7fa2af80-not-found-on-keyserver
was this command

`sudo wget -qO - https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub | sudo apt-key add -`

this is the output `Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)). OK`
I don't think it worked :(

Comment: "I am new to Linux" and "I am using Kali" does not go well together. Read [this](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me) then pick a different distribution.

Comment: See also "Non-Kali Repositories" in [the docs.](https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories/)